# How to download a file generated with JavaScript, avoiding automatic opening of Chome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, download, base64, blob

I am developing a JavaScript little webmail.

I receive from the server a Base64-encoded string, that represents a file (it could be whatever type). I decode the string, a map it to a `Uint8Array`, and with it, I generate a `Blob` object with I create a data URI with

```
FileReader.readAsDataURL(blob)
```

Until here is pretty straightforward, but I am having problem with the download part.

I put the DataURI in

```
window.open(dataURI)
```

But chrome opens a new window and display my image, or my text. But I need to avoid this behaviour, and download the file instead.

I have red that this could be done with `Content-Disposition "attachment"` but I am not sure if it is my case, because I am generating the file from a string from the server.

Anyone who can help me understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to use "saveAs" ?

```
saveAs(blob, "hello.zip");
```

In the case you need wide browser support you could try polifill. [More information](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/write_zip.html)

I am pretty sure you can set the type of the blob

```
var blob = new Blob(["Hello world!"], { type: "application/download" });
```

**Edit:**

without FileSaver.js:

```
var blob = new Blob(["Hi stack"], {type: 'application/download'});
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(e) {
    window.open(reader.result);
}
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

**Edit:**

Documentation and browser support information ("Browser compatibility" tab):

- [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)
- [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)

Comment: This suppose that I use `FileSave.js`, which I don't

Comment: That is exactly my current implementation, but it doesn't download the file, it opens it.

Comment: it's open because of "window.open" but after window is opened - browser start to download file. In the case if you use "{type: 'text/plane'}" browser will open page with text "Hi stack"

Comment: yeah you are right, I didn't notice it. Can you link me some documentation of it? I want to see if it works over browsers, and the original doc. I can't find them

Comment: I know you hate me, but I was talking about some docs or info about the "application/download" type. I can't find anything 'official' or that explain why it works

Comment: hater gonna hate :) I am not sure what exactly you want to read. It's a lot information. "MIME type". For example - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME

Comment: Remain to me the doubt about 'application/download' MIME type that I don't find any reference to it, anywhere! Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: 'application/download' could be some widely spread old bogus mimetype. I also could not find exactly this type (but I used it and got no problem). The better way would be to take some real type of course, depends from the file type you download.